# connecting to multiple databases on different servers in php

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I am trying to connect to two different databses using php

```
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $con= mysqli_connect("localhost", "phpapp", "phpapp", "hazard") or die("error connecting database 1".mysqli_error($con));
    $con_vpn= mysqli_connect("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "user", "pass", "db_name") or die("error connecting database 2".mysqli_error($con_vpn));
```

When I run the application it is showing error : `error connecting database 2.` It is not even printing the error.

thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're trying to use a handle from a failed connection. Since the connection failed, that handle is invalid. That's why there `mysqli_connect_error()`, which will return the error message from the LAST attempted connection.

```
$con_vpn = mysqli_connect(....) or die(mysqli_connect_error());
```

Note that the connect_error function takes no parameters - it doesn't need any.